# Excel to word doc macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an excel sheet in which the first column has page names and the second column has corresponding content. I need word documents to populate the list, so the first cell will be the name of the document and the second cell will be the corresponding content.

So if there are 10 docs I will get 10 rows populated.

How can I do that using excel macros?

Comment: It sounds like some VBA would be needed to do file creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to review all the rows with content and for each row generate a Word document, insert the content from column2 and then save it using the name specified in column1.  You could do this with the following code inside Excel VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateDocs()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lastRow, loopIndex, docName, docContent
Dim oWord: Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim oDocument
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For loopIndex = 1 To lastRow
    docName = ws.Range("A" & loopIndex).Value
    docContent = ws.Range("B" & loopIndex).Value
    Set oDocument = oWord.Documents.Add
    With oDocument
        .Range.Text = docContent
        .SaveAs "C:\temp\" & docName & ".docx"
    End With
    oDocument.Close
Next

Set oDocument = Nothing
oWord.Quit
Set oWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

This code assumes that your document names are in column A and your document content is in column B, and also starts on row 1.  You would need to adjust for where your data really is.

The code determines the last populated row in column A (again change this as necessary), then loops across all rows, reads the document name and content, creates a word document, inserts the content and saves the file with the specified name to your `C:\temp` folder (again, you can change this as necessary).